# how to get the running status of SP 2013 workflow

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow-manager

I want to get the running status of SharePoint 2013 workflow in my event receiver.
I am trying to use the below code  but its not working :

```
public static bool IsWorkflowRunning(SPListItem listItem, Guid workflowId)
{
    foreach (SPWorkflow workflow in listItem.Workflows)
    {
        if (workflow.ParentAssociation.BaseTemplate.Id == workflowId && workflow.InternalState == SPWorkflowState.Running)
            {
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false;
}
```

am  trying to trigger the `SharePoint designer 2013 workflow` that's deployed in a  `site collection` from an `event receiver`. and when I debugged the `event receiver` and perform some updates[ **listitem.update()** ] , it will trigger the workflow again, but  as per my requirement I need to trigger the `SP D 2013 WORKFLOW`  only once. Hence,for achieving this
I want to check the internal status of the workflow and if its running, I will not trigger the workflow again.

the above code i have written is , it seems from the SP 2010 WF API. it doesnt work for the workflows thats been created using Workflow Manager infrastructure in SP 2013.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to get SharePoint 2013 Workflow (subscription) you need to get it from WorkflowInstanceService and not from SPListItem. This is what I did to get instance of that Workflow and check its status.

You will need to have this reference `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServicesBase` and `using Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices;` directive.

```
public void IsWorkflowRunning(string workflowName, Guid listId, int listItemId)
{
   var workflowServiceManager = WorkflowServicesManager.Current;
   var workflowInstanceService = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService();
   foreach (var workflowInstance in workflowInstanceService.EnumerateInstancesForListItem(listId, listItemId)){
      var workflowSubscription = workflowServiceManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService().GetSubscription(workflowInstance.WorkflowSubscriptionId);
      if (workflowSubscription.Name == workflowName && workflowInstance.Status != WorkflowStatus.Terminated)//and another status workflow Cancelled, Completed
         return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```